# Invitare: sono invitato / ho invitato?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verb

Salve a tutti,

mi è capitata questa domanda in classe:
"invitare" è transitivo? Allora perché si dice "sono invitato ad una festa?".

Sono confusa, ogni aiuto sarà apprezzatissimo!

Ciao e grazie a tutti.

Comment: I verbi transitivi hanno sia la forma attiva che passiva. *Sono stato invitato* è la forma passiva.

Comment: "Sono invitato" è la forma passiva all'indicativo presente.

Answer (score 4):

L'organizzatore direbbe

> *Ho invitato Fiona alla festa per il compleanno di Asdrubale*

Fiona direbbe

> *Sono stata invitata alla festa per il compleanno di Asdrubale*

La prima è la forma attiva, la seconda è la forma passiva; il tempo verbale è identico, cioè passato prossimo.

Nel caso della tua frase, *sono invitata a una festa* è al presente indicativo:

> *Invito Fiona alla festa*
>
> *Sono invitata a una festa*

Answer (score 2):

Come da definizione della [**Treccani**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/invitare1/) il verbo invitare è **transitivo**

Nella frase `sono invitato ad una festa` si fa riferimento alla forma passiva dello stesso (riporto lo stralcio della definizione Treccani):

> Nel passivo, quando non sia specificato il genere dell’invito,
>   s’intende in genere essere invitato in casa di qualcuno, per un
>   pranzo, una cena, o anche solo per conversare: nel pomeriggio, sono
>   invitato dai miei vicini; domani sera sono invitato da un mio collega;
>   allora sei senz’altro invitato, o resti invitato, per domani; mi
>   dispiace di non poter accettare, sono già invitato altrove.